# Bootstrap Toggle doesnt work on Firefox, (working fine on Chrome)

Tags: html, firefox, toggle

**The probleme**

I want a button with a toggle-slider, so the user can click on the button who do something and he can also click on the toggle-slider to switch from ON to OFF.
Is working fine with chrome but not in Firefox.

**The code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>The toggle-slider doesn't work on firefox</h2>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block GotoMPMA" data-mesure-fid="1000">
 <span class="pull-right">
 <label class="toggle toggle-switch" data-toggle="toggle">
 <input class="toggle-slider" value="1041"  data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox">
 <div class="toggle-slider">
 </div>
 </label>
 </span>
 <span class="GotoMyData-label">This button do something
 </span>
 </button>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Thank you in advance**

> **THE SOLUTION** Is a workaround but is working well for me

```
<div class="grid-container" style="border:1px solid; border-color: #ddd; border-radius: 8px; margin-top:5px; background-color:#f4f4f4; display: grid;grid-template-columns: 90% auto;">
<div id="thebutton">
<button type="button" style="border:none; font-size: 15px; background-color:transparent" class="btn btn-default btn-block GotoMPMA" data-mesure-fid="1033">Title</button></div>
<div id="thetoggle">
<label class="toggle toggle-switch" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;" data-toggle="toggle">
<label class="toggle toggle-switch" data-toggle="toggle">
<input class="toggle-slider" value="1033" checked="" data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox">
<div class="toggle-slider"></div></label></label></div></div>
```

> Enjoy

Comment: not working in IE and firefox

Answer (score 0):

When opened in firefox you can see within the console that it is having issues loading the following CDN's -

[image]

Try a different CDN for your bootstrap or install locally...

Comment: I have my whole application using this CDN in differents places, i really dont want to use other CDN's just for this little thing. And i have already install it locally.

Comment: If you go to https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css and https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js in Firefox does it show as untrusted? If so add an exception and re try this will then work. 

Looks as though Firefox has a problem with those cdn's I am afraid.

Comment: No, both show up the same code in chrome and Firefox

Comment: In which case do you get any errors in your Firefox console when you run your application?

Comment: I dont have any errors in Firefox, simpli when i try to switch from ON to OFF (and of course also from OFF to ON) the application take me to the link of the button and is not changing the state of my toggle-slider.